# Open link in the same tab for Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Is it possible to enforce opening a link in the same tab with Firefox?

There are some cases where I don't want an extra tab to be opened.

Comment: You mean like this? http://www.ghacks.net/2009/07/03/force-firefox-to-open-links-in-same-tab/

Comment: I mentioned not always in same tab,but on some key-combiantion

Answer (score 9):

From https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/970999 :

- In about:config page (confirm that you'll be careful)
- Enter browser.link.open_newwindow in the search field
- Double click `browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction` and set value to 0
- Double click `browser.link.open_newwindow` and set value to 1

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It's really suprising that a feature/behavior that is default in other browsers is not only not default in firefox as well, but also not able to be changed to in the preferences menues. Your solution worked like a charm. 
For those of you wondering why someone would want this feature.. I prefer using middle click to open new tabs and the forward/back buttons to quickly cycle back and forth between search engine results and results i browse to. Its a faster workflow. It's all done from the mouse in place with no need to move the cursor to tabs to interact with them.

Comment: This setup allows to fully control which tab a link will be opened in: `browser.link.open_newwindow` set to 1 forces links to open in the current tab if you *left-click* them, and conveniently, *middle-click* still opens them in a new tab, so nothing is lost.

Comment: Watch out, though, this however also replaces non-browser-origin new Tab. When I click a link somewhere else, it opens the link in Firefox and replaces the current tab with it...

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to achieve this is to just drag the link into the address bar at the top of firefox (the long white bar with http;//superuser.com/questions/blah/blah/blah in it).  The contents will be replaced by the destination of the link and the link will open in the current page.

Comment: yes, i see, and it's not so convinient as for opening in new tab -j ust click on scroll button

Comment: this was very useful for me when trying to get the request details for a downloaded file, which does not appear in the inspector's networks tab, and to the `about:downloads` mozilla forgot to add the copy as cURL option

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on what add-ons you use, but on my set-up the CTRL key with left click on the mouse does what you want.

Comment: it opens new tab in background

Comment: Sorry - for me normal left click opens in same tab, CTRL click in new tab, SHIFT click in new window. In google search for example I use CTRL click to open search results in new tabs. I have Tab Mix Plus add-on loaded.

Comment: @BrianA Yes, this is the default behaviour in Firefox. CTRL click opens the link in a new tab. But the question was how to open it in the same tab. Normal left click doesn't have a fixed behavior. The web pages define the behavior for each link individually. Usually they are opened in the same tab though. As far as I know there is no way for the user to force a single link to open in the same tab with a simple key+click action, in contrast to forcing it to open in a new tab or window.